# How to Find Average of Numbers within a Single Cell

Tags: excel, split, formula

I've been working on this problem for awhile now and I am able to break this out using multiple cells and eventually get the average. But I am unable to construct a single formula to work out the average.

The data will be dynamic, from 2 to more than 8.
Idea is that I can paste the data into a cell and the Average will compute in another cell.

As mentioned, I was able to break it out using many separate cells and also vba, but was thinking of making the spreadsheet clear with a single cell to do this work.

Using this as an example data set:

ABC 106.375/DF 106.99/G 106.5/JK 99.5/

Output: Average = 104.84125

Just trying to retrieve the 3rd number in the data has put my formula into a huge mess and unneeded complication. =MID(G3,LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1))+LEN(MID(G3,LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1))+2,FIND("/",G3,LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1)))-2))+3,FIND("/",G3,LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1))+LEN(MID(G3,LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1))+2,FIND("/",G3,LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1)))-2))+3)-(LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1))+LEN(MID(G3,LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1))+2,FIND("/",G3,LEN(LEFT(G3,FIND("/",G3)-1)))-2))+2)-1)

I feel so limited that i am unable to keep variables and I am not even at the point when can pull all the numbers together to compute the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex-based user defined function.

```
Option Explicit

Function avgNumsOnly(str As String, _
                  Optional delim As String = ", ")
    Dim n As Long, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    avgNumsOnly = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "\d*\.?\d+"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            'resize the nums array to accept the matches
            ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
            'populate the nums array with the matches
            For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                nums(n) = CDbl(cmat.Item(n))
            Next n
            'average the nums array
            avgNumsOnly = Application.Average(nums)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeeped, appreciate the vba code solution, I've manged to implement a macro as well, but your coding is way more elegant than mine. I am however looking for this to be reflected as a one line formula in a cell.

Comment: See added image.

Comment: oh wow! i learnt something new! thanks a million jeep! i didnt know you can write up functions and reference them like this. is this what you mean by "regex-based user defined function"?

Comment: Yes, a UDF can be used on the worksheet or to collect and assign values in a sub procedure.

Comment: really, thank you for this Jeeped, i was always limited to having excel formulas separated from macros, this really opened new ways for me to work with excel. tyvm